# IPTables only allow localhost access

Tags: iptables

I have struggled throughout the years to get a solid understanding on iptables.  Any time I try and read through the man pages my eyes start to glaze over.

I have a service that I only want to allow the localhost to have access to.

**What terms (or configuration, if someone is feeling generous) should I Google for to allow only localhost host to have access to a given port?**

Comment: What port is this service running on?

Comment: 44344, its a service written in-house

Comment: I would like to change my nick temporarily for 'iptablesrules' but I can't

Comment: @Art, they only suck because I dont understand them :)

Comment: @iptablessuck actually it looks like I can. But I won't cause I'm not sure I will be able to change it back :)

Comment: You  better post your current configuration. `iptables --list`

Comment: "Any time I try and read through the man pages my eyes start to glaze over." That's what it was like for me until I've found [these](https://netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO//packet-filtering-HOWTO.html) [two](https://netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO//NAT-HOWTO.html) howto's. Short and easy to understand.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

If by service you mean a specific port, then the following two lines should work. Change the "25" to whatever port you're trying to restrict.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s localhost --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j DROP
```

Comment: "Anything coming from localhost to port 25, accept" and the second rule says "Drop anything coming into port 25".  The first line is processed first, allowing localhost, and anything else will get dropped by the second line.  Yes?

Comment: That's correct!

Comment: @Hyppy, how would you "undo" this?

Comment: @tester type those commands again, but replace `-A` with `-D`

Comment: Will these rules be saved after reboot?

Comment: @Astronaut type 'sudo service iptables save' to save the changes. then reboot. you can check whether changes were saved by typing 'sudo iptables -L'

Comment: I tried 'sudo service iptables save' but it returns 'iptables: unrecognized service'

The 2 lines given in the answer work though.

Comment: @Vagabond https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52376/why-do-iptables-rules-disappear-when-restarting-my-debian-system

Answer (score 35):

I'd recommend:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -p tcp --dport $APP_PORT -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport $APP_PORT -j DROP
```

Because, self-addressed packets do not necessarily have 127.0.0.1 as its source, but they all 'enter' from the `lo` interface.

Now, if you *really* want to understand `iptables` the first thing you should do is to download and print good diagrams explaining the relations of the `netfilter` tables. Here are two great ones:

- http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki?search=iptables - very complex, but the refrence
- http://vinojdavis.blogspot.com/2010/04/packet-flow-diagrams.html - the upper diagram is much more understandable, though not as complete

Finally, read a lot of `iptables` HOWTO's. The practical examples would help you get up-to-speed real quick :)

Comment: ty!  `lo` shows up for me after using these commands with the last command from this link http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-display-linux-iptables-loaded-rules/  `iptables -L -v -n --line-numbers`

Comment: @Gracchus I find it much easier to use `iptables-save` , save the output to a file, edit it with `vim` or `emacs`, and reimport the edited file using `iptables-apply`

Comment: I think depending on the use case, the second rule should explicitly REJECT instead of drop silently. Is it dropped silently as a best practice? Is REJECT safe to use?

Comment: @tech-pro Yes, REJECT is safe to use. It depends on what you are trying to accomplish and whether you want to be courteous to people trying to use the port. REJECT will send back a TCP RST packet telling the client that the machine is up but the port is closed. If you are closing a port that people might legitimately expect to use, then REJECT is good. If you expect only port scanners then DROP is better.

Comment: I had a web server running on the port that I want be accessible only via local host. In other to deny immediately to someone who uses from the browser I thought REJECT might be better. If it's dropped the browser hangs on till the timeout occurs. Does reject make sense in this use case?

Comment: @TechPro depends on whether you want to annoy people accessing that port or not :-) ... for ports that are not open to the public, only to localhost (by design), I put in `DROP`. So someone who's being nosy will have a practical joke played upon them. (Does not deter determined crackers, though, but a good lesson for too-nosy employees.) :D

Comment: @pepoluan Can you provide an example or two when self-addressed packets don't have `127.0.0.1` as their source address?

Comment: @x-yuri For example, I run `unbound` as DNS Cache, in front of `dnscrypt-proxy`. `unbound` binds to `127.0.53.1:53`, and `dnscrypt-proxy` binds to `127.0.53.2:53`. When an app requests either unbound or dnscrypt-proxy to resolve an FQDN, guess what source address will unbound/dnscrypt-proxy responds from?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I configured [iptables](https://www.netfilter.org/) to deny incoming requests from all ports except the ones I specifically want to allow. I didn't bother to allow 27107 because I mistakenly reasoned that iptables affects only traffic from other hosts, and I don't need to expose this instance of mongodb to the outside world.

I was wrong about iptables. When I added this rule, it worked again:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -s localhost --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT
```

This tells netfilter to accept incoming traffic to port 27017 as long as it's from the local host.

If I want to access this instance of mongo from a different host (such as my laptop), I can still do so with an [IP tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_tunnel).